# Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::getShippingAmount can't find implementation

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm searching for the code of the function getShippingAmount. I searched the whole codebase for "function getShippingAmount" and got no results.

In the class Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address there is a comment, that this method exists. I can see, that it's used from the core.

The Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address extends Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract but there I can't find the method either.

Can anybody help?
And how can I tackle that kind of problem next time by myself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getShippingAmount does not exist as a function. This is simply a magic getter and setters in Magento where Magento’s objects (that inherit from Varien_Object) have special “magic” getter & setter methods implemented with PHP’s magic `__call` method.

You can find the implementation `__call()` function in the Varien_Object.(lib/Varien/Object.php)

Comment: Oh, I've heard of magic getters. Thanks for pointing that out again! +1 for explining the __call() function in Varien_Object.